# Get last item URL

Tags: php, json

I have a data in following JSON sort of format in which I am trying to only get the very last URL which in my following example is `https://lastexample.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL.jpg` . Is there an easy way I can retrieve this via PHP?

```
{"https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],
"https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SY355_.jpg":[355,355],
"https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],
"https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SY450_.jpg":[450,450],
"https://lastexample.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL.jpg":[500,500]}
```

Comment: Thats a horribly unusable JSON Format. Can you fix the sending code?

Comment: I agree with Riggs. having the URL as a property of the object doesn't strike me as a very good format. Properties shouldn't really contain meaningful data themselves, they should be keys to the data. You _can_ retrieve the property name using PHP but it seems like fixing the data structure would be a better idea first.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes that's true its horrible json but that's how I am getting from the source file so I have to do something about it at my end, the format itself can't be improved

Comment: At least you should have been able to realize that this will decode to an array; after that, researching how to get the last element of an array in PHP would’ve been absolutely trivial ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, decode it into an array ([json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) then get the keys ([array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)), then the last entry ([end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)/[max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php)).

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SX425_.jpg": [425, 425],
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SY355_.jpg": [355, 355],
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SX466_.jpg": [466, 466],
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SY450_.jpg": [450, 450],
    "https://lastexample.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL.jpg": [500, 500]
}';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$keys = array_keys($array);

echo end($keys); // https://lastexample.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL.jpg
```

https://3v4l.org/MLbdt

Comment: Sorry to point it out but your code does not use end, it uses max ;-)

Comment: thanks for your quick response and that's a perfect solution

Comment: Why max and why not end?

Comment: I thought so too. But it's not, end returns a notice https://3v4l.org/qkMbE max does not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php 
$json = '{
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SX425_.jpg":[425,425],
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SY355_.jpg":[355,355],
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SX466_.jpg":[466,466],
    "https://example.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL._SY450_.jpg":[450,450],
    "https://lastexample.com/images/I/4162nAIaRCL.jpg":[500,500]
}';


$arr = json_decode($json,true);
$arrkeys = array_keys($arr);
$lastkey = end($arrkeys);
echo $lastkey; 
?>
```